# Does there exist a website that lists manufacturer of generic, store-brand items? Are private label brands worth it?

Tags: shopping

For instance, I'm certain that Shopper's Drugmart in Ontario, Canada does not manufacture its own shampoo, conditioner, diapers, tissue, kitchen spray, room deodorizer, etc. for its "Life Brand" products.

I'd like to try some of these but am interested in who is behind-the-scenes.

Does anyone know of such a listing?

Comment: Are you asking because it will help you determine if private label brands are a worthy alternative to regular brand labels?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If Life Brand shampoo for colour-treated hair is made by Helene-Curtis (for example), I will trust it with my colour-treated hair.

Comment: If that be the case please consider rewording the question or adding "are private label brands worth it?"  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately private label brands are like a badly kept secret.  People can guess who's actually manufacturing a product but no one will confirm directly.

The manufacturer and the retailer typically have an agreement not to disclose the information.  The are several reasons for this:

1. The manufacturer makes a premium version of the product and does not wish to see sales lost to the normally lower cost alternative.
2. The retailer wishes to capitalize on its branding.
3. The retailer may wish to have the flexibility to change manufacturers at any time.  This allows the same branding to be used.  e.g. The change in vendors for Girl Guide Cookies in Canada several years ago.  The vanilla never tasted quite the same. :-(

The only time there is an exception to this rule is when there is a serious health/safety concern with the product which results in a recall.  This is not always limited to the private label as most recalls are typically issued by manufacturers for a range of products.

As a general rule of thumb most private label brands are as good if not better than premium brands.  You just need to try them out to see if they meet your needs.  Usually this is inexpensive trial since they are priced lower.  For example, I switched to private label diapers and found them just as good as the #1 and #2 brands.

Comment: I agree. Wow, this is great to know. Thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I realize now that I the "Generic Brand List" post I previously entered did not really address your actual desired question, and I incorrectly titled that as a list for Generics, but that Wikipedia list was for Store brands, which is a handy and helpful list anyway... and it does do a fairly good job of defining the difference between Store and Generic brands in general.  I did come across a good suggestion that might be of help in determining apples to apples between National Brands and Store Brands: compare ingredients.  If they appear the same, and are listed in the same order, they most likely will be the same product. Hope this helps.